# Order of two threads trying to connect to two different remote machine giving different results

Tags: c#, .net, remote-access

I have an .NET Application which tries to initiate different installations on different remote machines. Before actual installation takes place the application connects to these remote machines and gets the existing versions of these installations  by spawning different threads (each thread is responsible for getting the existing version for a particular installation) for each remote machine.

In a particular case there are two calls to get existing version to two different machines where one call takes a longer time whereas the other takes very less time. Now the problem is the order in which the application spawns threads is making a difference. If I spawn the thread which takes more time to get version first the second thread(which takes lesser time) is failing to get the proper version since it is not able to connect to the remote machine. If i spawn the thread which takes lesser time to get version first both the threads return me the correct version.
I feel there is a race for some resource. Any clues?
Thanks in advance.

Some code snippets

```
class RemoteInstallable
{
//...other functions...
public override bool GetExistingVersion()
   {
            try
            {
                base.ExistingVersion = RemoteInstaller.GetExistingVersion(base.InstallInfo.VersionPath);
                return true;
            } 
   }
//....others..
};

GetAllVersions()
{
 foreach ( R as remoteinstallabe in ListofAllRemoteInstallables)
  {
    Thread T =  new Thread();
    //Use T to get version of R 
  }
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you'd show us some code...

Comment: Still not enough information here. It could be the Client but there could also be queuing at the Server. No race probably.

Comment: Since each thread is contacting only one server the queuing at Server is ruled out.